# MYSQL -- running dynamic query based on the week days

Tags: mysql

I have a table (tasks). It has (so far) userid and 7 columns, days of the week

```
+-----------+--+---+---+---+---+---+--+
| userid    | 1| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7|
+-----------+--+---+---+---+---+---+--+
| 123       | 1| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0|
+-----------+--+---+---+---+---+---+--+
| 456       | 1| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0|
+-----------+--+---+---+---+---+---+--+
```

I can run this simple query.

```
SELECT * FROM tasks AS t
 WHERE t.4 = TRUE
```

That works as intended. What I need is to run a query every day. Determine what day of the week it is, and select all of them if they are true.

I need first to determine what day of the week it is, and there is a function to do exactly that: `DAYOFWEEK(curdate())`

For example, if today is Wednesday, it will return 4.
How can I make it dynamic? I tried something along these lines, but without any success:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks AS t
     WHERE t.DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) = TRUE
```

I would need somehow to make dynamic selection.

Comment: Simply normalize your data into the structure `(userid - day of week - value)`.

Comment: Would you please provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Sample. You can use Prepare statement.

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT `userid`, `', DAYOFWEEK(NOW()),
 '` as `today` FROM tasks WHERE `',DAYOFWEEK(NOW()),'` = TRUE')
 INTO @myquery;  
PREPARE stmt FROM @myquery;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT CONCAT('SELECT `userid`, `', DAYOFWEEK(NOW()),'` as `today` FROM tasks') INTO @myquery;         
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> PREPARE stmt FROM @myquery;
ECUQuery OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB [bernd]> EXECUTE stmt;
+--------+-------+
| userid | today |
+--------+-------+
|    123 |     9 |
|    123 |     9 |
|    123 |  NULL |
|     12 |  NULL |
|    123 |     9 |
+--------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Comment: @Vedran Maricevic. - if you have any question you can alo call me. my phonenumber is in my profile. i am also from the 8 bit area

Comment: Great to see familiar face here :). Your answer if to the point, except how do I select only ones with TRUE.

Comment: I think the true is not necessary because the day of the week is the same as the column name. here my phonenumber 02163 9879851

Comment: Can't call you now :(. IN my example, it will return all results for the given day (4). But I need to return only the one with 1 (true).

Comment: i have changed it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

For your current design you need a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tasks 
WHERE CASE DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
  WHEN 1 THEN `1`
  WHEN 2 THEN `2`
  WHEN 3 THEN `3`
  WHEN 4 THEN `4`
  WHEN 5 THEN `5`
  WHEN 6 THEN `6`
  WHEN 7 THEN `7`
END
```

With a different design like:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
  `userid` INTEGER,
  `day` INTEGER,
  `val` BOOLEAN
);

INSERT INTO tasks
  (`userid`, `day`, `val`)
VALUES
  ('123', '1', true),
  ('123', '2', true),
  ('123', '3', false),
  ('123', '4', true),
  ('123', '5', true),
  ('123', '6', true),
  ('123', '7', false);
```

you could have a simple query like:

```
SELECT userid 
FROM tasks
WHERE day = DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) AND val
```